# ¿Cómo recorrer un arreglo multidimensional e imprimirlo en una tabla desde PHP?

Tags: php, ciclos

Tengo el siguiente arreglo;

```
$datos = array(
                            "nombre" => array("Juan Perez","Pablo Manrique","Nancy Peña"),
                            "direccion" => array("Cra. 45 # 45 -56","Clle. 23 # 12 -19 Sur","Av. 34 # 16 -12"),
                            "telefono" => array("3456789","3214567","2135423"),
                            "fecha" => array("23/12/1997","12/10/1980"," 07/06/2000"),
                            "color" => array("Amarillo","Verde","Verde"),
                            "significado" => array("Riqueza yalegría.","No se encuentra el significado","")
                        );
```

Y busco la forma de hacer una sola validación e imprimir en pantalla una tabla con los datos que se encuentran en cada arreglo, pero me sale todo en una columna.

Lo que busco realizar es algo como esto,

[image: cada ítem del array como valores de una columna]

**Esta es la condicion**

Si el nombre del color existe en un segundo arreglo que contiene: el nombre
del color y el significado de cada uno, en caso de encontrarlo, es necesario
escribir en una última columna de la Tabla  el significado del color, de lo
contrario debe escribir la frase “No se encuentra el significado”.

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
echo "<table border=1><tr><th>nombre</th>
                <th>direccion</th>
                <th>telefono</th>
                <th>fecha</th>
                <th>color</th>
                <th>significado</th></tr>";
            foreach ($datos as $value)
            {
                echo "<tr><td>".$value[0]."<td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td>".$value[1]."<td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td>".$value[2]."<td></tr>";
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si todos tus arrays tienen la misma longitud entonces podrías hacer esto:

```
$datos = array(
    "nombre" => array("Juan Perez","Pablo Manrique","Nancy Peña"),
    "direccion" => array("Cra. 45 # 45 -56","Clle. 23 # 12 -19 Sur","Av. 34 # 16 -12"),
    "telefono" => array("3456789","3214567","2135423"),
    "fecha" => array("23/12/1997","12/10/1980"," 07/06/2000"),
    "color" => array("Amarillo","Verde","Verde"),
    "significado" => array("Riqueza yalegría.","No se encuentra el significado","")
);

$nombres = $datos['nombre'];
$direcciones = $datos['direccion'];
$telefonos = $datos['telefono'];
$fechas = $datos['fecha'];
$colores = $datos['direccion'];
$significados = $datos['significado'];

echo "<table border=1><tr><th>nombre</th>
    <th>direccion</th>
    <th>telefono</th>
    <th>fecha</th>
    <th>color</th>
    <th>significado</th></tr>";




for ($i = 0; $i < count($nombres); $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$nombres[$i]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$direcciones[$i]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$telefonos[$i]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$fechas[$i]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$colores[$i]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$significados[$i]."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: La idea esta bien, solo tiene un pequeño error; deberías abrir solo `<tr>` en el primer `echo` y solo cerrar el `</tr>` en el último `echo`, de esa forma obtendrás el resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola @jfergt, gracias por tu interes, me ha sido util tu respuesta, y como lo dice Marcos Gallardo solo habia un pequeño error, pero es simple. Saludos.

Answer (score 5):

Aqui tienes el script:

La idea es iterar las columnas de tu arreglo datos, asignar cada uno de los arreglos para cada columna.

Finalmente se iteran y se hace el render de la tabla.

```
<?php
  $datos = array(
      "nombre" => array("Juan Perez","Pablo Manrique","Nancy Peña"),
      "direccion" => array("Cra. 45 # 45 -56","Clle. 23 # 12 -19 Sur","Av. 34 # 16 -12"),
      "telefono" => array("3456789","3214567","2135423"),
      "fecha" => array("23/12/1997","12/10/1980"," 07/06/2000"),
      "color" => array("Amarillo","Verde","Rojo"),
      "significado" => array("Riqueza yalegría.","No se encuentra el significado","No se encuentra el significado")
  );



   $contador = 0;

   foreach ($datos as $value) {
       switch ($contador) {
            case 0:
                $datosNombre = $value;
                break;
            case 1:
                $datosDireccion = $value;
                break;
            case 2:
                $datosTelefono = $value;
                break;
            case 3:
                $datosFecha = $value;
                break;
            case 4:
                $datosColor = $value;
                break;
            case 5:
                $datosSignificado = $value;
                break;
        }
        ++$contador;
   }

    echo "<table>";  
    for ($i=0; $i<count($datosNombre);++$i) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $datosNombre[$i];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $datosDireccion[$i];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $datosTelefono[$i];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $datosFecha[$i];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $datosColor[$i];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $datosSignificado[$i];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Saludos,

Comment: Hola @Jorge Londoño, gracias por tu interes, me ha sido util tu respuesta. Saludos.